# remove certain custom html from textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having one textarea in which some custom html is pasted. Now I want to remove if `<intensity>` > `<intensity>` is having some alphabet instead of numbers. Please take a look at my code. (as I change textarea value it should remove  parent tag which child is having "m" intensity value. In output results, it should remove parent `<intensity>` tag of `m` but in `64m` it should remove only `m` and keep `64`.)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.textarea').on("change keyup input",function() {
    if ($('.textarea').val($(" <div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").text()=='m')
    {$(this).parent().remove();}.
  });
});
//as I change textarea value it should remove <intensity> parent tag which child is having "m" intensity value.
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
      <intensity>
        <theta>20.9546</theta>
        <da>4.235900</da>
        <intensity>214</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>0</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>26.7488</theta>
        <da>3.330030</da>
        <intensity>999</intensity>
        <h>0</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>1</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>36.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>64m</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>36.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>m</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
    <intensity>
        <theta>68.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>54</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
</textarea>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().remove();` will remove your textarea control. Change that code to something else. Also, Why parent and child tag name same for `<intensity>`?

Comment: These `<intensity>` tags are same in previous code, its not in my hands to change it sir.

Comment: See my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948232/11027975).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will remove any inner `<intensity>` tag if it contains a non-numeric value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const ta=$('.textarea')
  ta.on("change keyup input",function() {
    const dom=$("<div>"+ta.val()+"</div>");
    dom.find("intensity intensity").each(function(){if (this.textContent==="m") $(this).parent().remove() })
    ta.val(dom.html());
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea' cols="40" rows="40" >
      <intensity>
        <theta>20.9546</theta>
        <da>4.235900</da>
        <intensity>214</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>0</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>26.7488</theta>
        <da>3.330030</da>
        <intensity>999</intensity>
        <h>0</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>1</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>36.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>64m</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
      <intensity>
        <theta>36.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>m</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
    <intensity>
        <theta>68.7175</theta>
        <da>2.445600</da>
        <intensity>54</intensity>
        <h>1</h>
        <k>1</k>
        <l>0</l>
        <F></F>
      </intensity>
</textarea>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, but I want to reomve the parent intensity tag if its child intensity tag is having only alphabets. Also in 64m, I want to keet it as 64, but in only m, it should remove its parent tag. Thank you again for your response.

Comment: I have removed parent `<intensity>` tag by using `$(this).parent().remove()` but it is also removing `64m` parent. I want to remove only `m` from `64m`

Comment: Ok, If that is what you want, then I have changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = "<intensity>test</intensity><intensity>123</intensity>";
var result = body.replace(/<intensity>(.*?)<\/intensity>/g, "");

console.log(result);
```

With above code you can iterate each match and check if equals numbers and replace or change the regular expression to match numbers only, because `(.*?)` matches any string.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. It will remove parent node `<intensity>` when child node `<intensity>` contains only `m`. It will also remove alphabet `m` from child node `<intensity>`

```
$('.textarea').on("change keyup input", function () {
    const dom = $("<div>" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
    dom.find("intensity intensity").each(function () {
        var int = this.innerText;
        if (int == 'm') {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
        else {
            $(this).text(int.replaceAll('m', ''));
        }
    })
    $(this).val(dom.html());
});
```